# How to override style of nested Material UI component from the ancestors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am using a component from an external library that does not allow me to change much of its style, but I would like to change the style of a button that is a material ui button, when inspecting the element it clearly shows the classes **MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit**

how can I override the MuiIconButton-root style, for instance? this is my component:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={classes.myComponent}>
                <3rdPartyComponent />
            </div>
        );

    }
}


export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent)
```

I have tried declaring my styles function as follows, without success:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  myComponent: {
    "&.MuiIconButton-root": {
      padding: "0px"
    }
  }
});
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Material-UI styles document:https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Comment: @keikai I have already gone through that documentation and could not find how to override "grandchildren"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let's say that the class name generated for `myComponent` is `myComponent-jss123`. The selector you used in your styles (`&.MuiIconButton-root`) would be equivalent to `.myComponent-jss123.MuiIconButton-root` which would match any element that has **both** of these classes applied to it. I believe your intent was to match icon buttons which are **descendants** of the `div` on which you are applying the `myComponent` class. In this case you need to use the [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) represented by a space, so the appropriate styles would look like the following:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  myComponent: {
    "& .MuiIconButton-root": {
      padding: 0
    }
  }
});
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import React from "react";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import DeleteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Delete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  myComponent: {
    "& .MuiIconButton-root": {
      padding: 0
    }
  }
});
const ThirdPartyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      I'm a third party component that contains an IconButton:
      <IconButton color="primary">
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.myComponent}>
      <ThirdPartyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit target descendant icon button]

Related documentation:

- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.4#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator